# How to use this code in matlab? (set path opencv)

Tags: matlab, opencv

I'm using MATLAB R2013a x64 and Win7 x64. I installed OpenCV 2.4.7.2 to the path (C:\opencv).

How do i to use this code in matlab?

```
mex -Lpath_to_opencv_lib_dir -Ipath_to_opencv_include_dir -lcv -lcxcore me_HaarDetectOpenCV.cpp
```

Comment: Could you clarify? Where did this line come from? What do you want to do with it? Right now it's generating a mex file for you - converting a .cpp file to something that you can call from Matlab. Presumably you just call the function defined in that file as you would any other function (assuming you put the output in your path).

Comment: @Floris  http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/calvin/calvin_upperbody_detector/downloads/README.html

Quick start >> 4

Comment: Don't points 4. and 5. ff in your link tell you exactly what you need to know? Not sure why you are coming here for advice.

Comment: @Floris not work ?
>> mex -L 'C:\OpenCV-2.4.7\build\x64\vc10\lib\' -I 'C:\OpenCV-2.4.7\build\include\' -l cv -l cxcore me_HaarDetectOpenCV.cpp

Comment: Do you have a C++ compiler properly installed on your system? I suggest you look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-mex-files.html for help on getting `mex` to work.

Comment: @Floris   yes. visual studio 2012 & sdk 7.1

Comment: @goldpower: Why does it not work? What error message do you get?

Comment: @Floris   
Error: 'cv' not found.

Answer (score 1):

For the following command:

```
mex -Lpath_to_opencv_lib_dir -Ipath_to_opencv_include_dir -lcv -lcxcore me_HaarDetectOpenCV.cpp
```

to work, you need to substitute some things. Specifically, where it says

```
path_to_opencv_lib_dir
```

you need to put the *actual* path to the directory where you store the OpenCV library, not the words `path_to_opencv_lib_dir` - see http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html for some information on how to do these things in Visual Studio, and realize there may be an environment variable (e.g. $OPENCV_DIR) that contains the path you need.

the same is true for `path_to_opencv_include_dir`